# High side P-channel mosfet switch for BLDC driver (42V ~13A at peak)

Tags: mosfet, switches, bjt, brushless-dc-motor, high-side

I'm trying to design high-side switch for BLDC motor controller(42V ~13A). I understand that low-side switch is more efficient in this case, but controller schematics(bought as is) has an issue. It applies 42V to signal pins in case if ground is not connected. So here is schematics that I supposed to have:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMm7Jw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So few questions:

1. What transistor do I need to have in this case?(Q1)
2. Do I need pullup resistor R5 at all?
3. Overall how this scheme might be improved?

Thank you!

Comment: You might spend some time finding the websites where those who reflash the firmware of RC hobby ESC's (with simonk, blheli, etc) have documented their schematics and part selections.  The main spec on that transistor would be the allowed voltages.  That resistor is a pull-down, not a pull-up...   Broad design reviews or requests for "improvements" aren't really on-topic - the best advice really is to start with something proven, thus the earlier reference to actual hobby ESC's.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, probably I was not completely clear in schematic description, but I don't suppose to create BLDC driver, I only need circuit to switch existing driver power on or off, depend signal from arduino. So circuit is as simple as it is.

Comment: You really shouldn't switch a BLDC driver on and off, but rather control its existing switches via command.  Anyway, even if you really wanted to to this inadvisable thing, you could still learn by examining how the drivers themselves do their implicitly required high side switching.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I only would like to have all circuits powered off until Arduino powered up and initialized.

Comment: Putting another power FET inline with the BLDC is a fundamentally bad idea, you should use the drivers arming sequence instead.

Comment: R5 is a pull down resistor, not a pull up.  It's very odd that its value is much less than R4.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a logic level n-MOSFET for driving the high side MOSFET.

Notice the freewheeling diode which is mandatory when driving an inductive load like a motor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDOT4v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You have to be careful about using PMOS as a high side switch if your supply voltage is anything over 20V. PMOS usually have a low VGS maximum, which gets violated by this circuit; i.e. when you activated M2 to get M1 to start conducting, magic smoke. (The datasheet for the IRF5305 VGSmax is +/-20V, as with most PMOS). There are some clever ways to get around this though and still use a PMOS on the high side

Comment: @Ocanath Vgs is either 0V or ~-12V. The maximum rating for Vgs is not violated. Note, that the source of the pMOS is connected to 42V.

Comment: ah yep, my mistake. should have looked more closely at your resistor values

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX55cr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
There's a couple issues that I see. One being that your Mosfet is only rated for 13V higher than your rail. With that amount of current plus an inductive load, you are likely to see voltage spikes well above that. The second being that your mosfet is going to turn on very slow due to the large gate resistance that it has. That large of a gate resistance will likely generate a lot of heat because the mosfet will be in the active region for a longer period of time.

The option that I included is a little bit more costly but it avoids using a P-Channel and is a standard way of using a N-Channel as a high side switch. I also picked a slightly higher voltage mosfet (100v) but you may still need to go higher than that. This uses an isolated DC-DC to reference the isolated gate driver and the source of the mosfet to the same potential which allows you to use the N-Channel as a high side switch. I know this isn't exactly what your question is, but I though it may be useful to know that this is also an option.

Comment: Thank you, for your suggestion, this idea to use optocouple in couple with high-side N-channel mosfet looks great. The cost is not what I worry about for now, since it's my pet-project.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure you knew that wasn't an optocoupler in that schematic. It's an isolated driver which has an opto coupler built into it to isolate the driver section of it. The reason being, if you just use an opto coupler instead of the isolated driver, you still have the issue of higher gate resistance and end up with two different results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of relays in this sort of application. Relays have very low resistance, so little power loss.

Most arduino users drive the relay with a bjt. If you do this, use a diode across the coil to absorb any inductive spikes when turning off the relay. Simple and effective. Use a relay that is open when unpowered.

[image]