# Driving a 12V ~500mA load with a 3.3V logic level special pin GPIO0 on a ESP07s and MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, schematics, esp8266, gpio

As some of you know GPIO0 is a special pin that needs to be pulled HIGH during start-up else the ESP07s enters flash mode.

I've tried to read up, but it feels like I know too little to know what to search for.
This is my schematic, will it work?

[image: schematic, GPIO0 pulled high connected to the gate of a pmos with a 1k resistor in series, pmos source is 12V, pmos Drain is connected to a load that draws around 200mA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not work.

To turn off an P-Channel MOSFET, its gate must at the same voltage as the source.

- When GPIO0 is at 0 V, the MOSFET receives 12 V
- When GPIO0 is at 3.3 V, the MOSFET receives 12 V - 3.3 V = 8.7 V.

In both cases, the MOSFET receives a gate voltage. Therefore, the MOSFET is always on. You have no way to turn off the MOSFET.

---

What you want there is a "high-side switch". When we want a high-side switch, we usually buy a ready-made IC to do the job. We rarely would make a high-side switch from scratch. If you want to make a high-side switch from scratch, [here is a circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/527377/high-side-p-channel-mosfet-switch-for-bldc-driver-42v-13a-at-peak). Note that it requires an additional transistor and that the polarity is inverted.

Comment: I updated the schematic, something like that?

Comment: Yes. but only if the motor is tiny.

Comment: I updated with some datasheet reading questions, can each output handle 450+ mA or is it all outputs combined?

Comment: This is getting to far from the original question. It's time to start a new thread with questions about driving a motor with the ULN2003.

Comment: My original question was on how to drive a load from the GPIO0 pin, that is still the case. Sure, I went in the wrong direction in my suggestion, but I guess you will not get the points for taking time and pointing me in the correct direction. I'll modify this and start a new question because of the system